# How to merge code in github?

Tags: javascript, git, github

I am new to github.

I want to share code with my teammates.

Suppose i have a js file having code {previous code};
i pushed this to github remote.

now my friend pulled the remote repository and made some changes .
let it be `{previous code} + {new code 1}`.

Now i made some changes. let `{previous code} + {new code 2}`.
now how to get this all code at one place by merging. i.e 
`{previous code} + {new code 1} + {new code 2}`

more info: we are using webstorm IDE.

Comment: Your friend does Commit -> Pull -> Push. And then you do Commit -> Pull -> merge using your git hub source tree IDE -> Push. Did I get your question right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work on the same branch you simply have to pull the code from Github.
If you use different branches, you will need to merge your changes. You can do it locally with Webstorm.

---

[image]

---

Here is a screenshot where to find the git command under webstorm.

[image]